# Index and IndexMut implementations to return borrowed vectors

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've been working on a multi-dimensional array library, toying around with different interfaces, and ran into an issue I can't seem to solve.  This may be a simple misunderstanding of lifetimes, but I've tried just about every solution I can think of, to no success.

The goal: implement the Index and IndexMut traits to return a borrowed vector from a 2d matrix, so this syntax can be used `mat[rowind][colind]`.

A (very simplified) version of the data structure definition is below.

```
pub struct Matrix<T> {
    shape: [uint, ..2],
    dat: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: FromPrimitive+Clone> Matrix<T> {
    pub fn new(shape: [uint, ..2]) -> Matrix<T> {
        let size = shape.iter().fold(1, |a, &b| { a * b});
        // println!("Creating MD array of size: {} and shape: {}", size, shape)
        Matrix{
            shape: shape,
            dat: Vec::<T>::from_elem(size, FromPrimitive::from_uint(0u).expect("0 must be convertible to parameter type"))
        }
    }
    pub fn mut_index(&mut self, index: uint) -> &mut [T] {
        let base = index*self.shape[1];
        self.dat.mut_slice(base, base + self.shape[1])
    }
}

fn main(){
    let mut m = Matrix::<f32>::new([4u,4]);
    println!("{}", m.dat)
    println!("{}", m.mut_index(3)[0])
}
```

The mut_index method works exactly as I would like the IndexMut trait to work, except of course that it doesn't have the syntax sugar.  The first attempt at implementing IndexMut made me wonder, since it returns a borrowed reference to the specified type, I really want to specify `[T]` as a type, but it isn't a valid type.  So the only option is to specify `&mut [T]` like this.

```
impl<T: FromPrimitive+Clone> IndexMut<uint, &mut [T]> for Matrix<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: &uint) -> &mut(&mut[T]) {
        let base = index*self.shape[1];
        &mut self.dat.mut_slice(base, base + self.shape[1])
    }
}
```

This complains about a missing lifetime specifier on the trait impl line.  So I try adding one.

```
impl<'a, T: FromPrimitive+Clone> IndexMut<uint, &'a mut [T]> for Matrix<T> {
    fn index_mut(&'a mut self, index: &uint) -> &mut(&'a mut[T]) {
        let base = index*self.shape[1];
        &mut self.dat.mut_slice(base, base + self.shape[1])
    }
}
```

Now I get `` method `index_mut` has an incompatible type for trait: expected concrete lifetime, but found bound lifetime parameter 'a [E0053] ``.  Aside from this I've tried just about every combination of one and two lifetimes I can think of, as well as creating a secondary structure to hold a reference that is stored in the outer structure during the indexing operation so a reference to *that* can be returned instead, but that's not possible for Index.  The final answer may just be that this isn't possible, given the response on this old [github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/8355), but that would seem to be a problematic limitation of the Index and IndexMut traits.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, this is not possible, but when Dynamically Sized Types lands I believe it will become possible.

Let’s look at [the signature](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html):

```
pub trait IndexMut<Index, Result> {
    fn index_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, index: &Index) -> &'a mut Result;
}
```

(Note the addition of the `<'a>` compared with what the docs say; I’ve filed [#16228](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16228) about that.)

`'a` is an arbitrary lifetime, but it is important that it is specified on the *method*, not on the impl as a whole: it is in absolute truth a generic parameter to the method. I’ll show how it all comes out here with the names `'ρ₀` and `'ρ₁`. So then, in this attempt:

```
impl<'ρ₀, T: FromPrimitive + Clone> IndexMut<uint, &'ρ₀ mut [T]> for Matrix<T> {
    fn index_mut<'ρ₁>(&'ρ₁ mut self, index: &uint) -> &'ρ₁ mut &'ρ₀ mut [T] {
        let base = index * self.shape[1];
        &mut self.dat.mut_slice(base, base + self.shape[1])
    }
}
```

This satisfies the requirements that (a) all lifetimes must be explicit in the `impl` header, and (b) that the method signature matches the trait definition: `Index` is `uint` and `Result` is `&'ρ₀ mut [T]`. Because `'ρ₀` is defined on the impl block (so that it can be used as a parameter there) and `'ρ₁` on the method (because that’s what the trait defines), `'ρ₀` and `'ρ₁` cannot be combined into a single named lifetime. (You could call them both `'a`, but this is shadowing and does not change anything except for the introduction of a bit more confusion!)

However, this is not enough to have it all work, and it will indeed not compile, because `'ρ₀` is not tied to anything, nor is there to tie it to in the signature. And so you cannot cast `self.data.mut_slice(…)`, which is of type `&'ρ₁ mut [T]`, to `&'ρ₀ mut [T]` as the lifetimes do not match, nor is there any known subtyping relationship between them (that is, it cannot structurally be demonstrated that the lifetime `'ρ₀` is less than—a subtype of—`'ρ₁`; although the return type of the method would make that clear, it is not so at the basic type level, and so it is not permitted).

Now as it happens, `IndexMut` isn’t as useful as it should be anyway owing to [#12825](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12825), as `matrix[1]` would always use `IndexMut` and never `Index` if you have implemented both. I’m not sure if that’s any consolation, though!

The solution comes in Dynamically Sized Types. When that is here, `[T]` will be a legitimate unsized type which can be used as the type for `Result` and so this will be the way to write it:

```
impl<T: FromPrimitive + Clone> IndexMut<uint, [T]> for Matrix<T> {
    fn index_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, index: &uint) -> &'a mut [T] {
        let base = index * self.shape[1];
        &mut self.dat.mut_slice(base, base + self.shape[1])
    }
}
```

… but that’s not here yet.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  It does make sense, but I admit I'm surprised that the solution may be found in DSTs.  Somehow I was thinking, or perhaps hoping, that there was some way to tie the method's generic lifetime into a the trait definition lifetime.

Comment: DST fixes up a few of these sorts of things because `[T]` becomes a valid type where a generic `&U` or `&mut U` will then work for `U = [T]`, producing `&[T]` or `&mut [T]`. It takes the reference lifetime problem out of the way.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Is it not possible to remove the dependency on DST here by wrapping the result in another type (which would be parameterized by a lifetime and contain a slice) ? For a `Matrix` I could imagine returning a `RowMut<'a, T>` type for example, which would itself implement `IndexMut`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don’t see how that would help. Elucidate?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Sorry, I just noticed the issue. I was thinking of using a proxy (`Row`), but the specification of the return type of `IndexMut::index_mut` precludes it. This is very inconvenient.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: For information, [this is what I would have liked](http://is.gd/cdrahd). I feel that preventing using proxies will unduly restrict the use of proxies (and thus views), was there any discussion over this interface ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. you could have `trait Index<'a, Index, Result> { fn index(&'a self) -> Result; }`, but that would damage the intrinsic semantics of indexing. (a) You could no longer guarantee based solely on observing `a[b]` what the lifetime of that expression would be. (b) It would also wreak havoc on `IndexMove` versus `Index` versus `IndexMut`—they would need to be rethought and reimplemented considerably differently, and I don’t think the outcome would be positive.

Answer (score 2):

This code works in Rust 1.25.0 (and probably has for quite a while)

```
extern crate num;

use num::Zero;

pub struct Matrix<T> {
    shape: [usize; 2],
    dat: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T: Zero + Clone> Matrix<T> {
    pub fn new(shape: [usize; 2]) -> Matrix<T> {
        let size = shape.iter().product();

        Matrix {
            shape: shape,
            dat: vec![T::zero(); size],
        }
    }

    pub fn mut_index(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut [T] {
        let base = index * self.shape[1];
        &mut self.dat[base..][..self.shape[1]]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = Matrix::<f32>::new([4; 2]);
    println!("{:?}", m.dat);
    println!("{}", m.mut_index(3)[0]);
}
```

You can enhance it to support `Index` and `IndexMut`:

```
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

impl<T> Index<usize> for Matrix<T> {
    type Output = [T];

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &[T] {
        let base = index * self.shape[1];
        &self.dat[base..][..self.shape[1]]
    }
}

impl<T> IndexMut<usize> for Matrix<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut [T] {
        let base = index * self.shape[1];
        &mut self.dat[base..][..self.shape[1]]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = Matrix::<f32>::new([4; 2]);
    println!("{:?}", m.dat);
    println!("{}", m[3][0]);

    m[3][0] = 42.42;
    println!("{:?}", m.dat);
    println!("{}", m[3][0]);
}
```